# Sorting Data by the Content of ALL Cells in the Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to sort rows of cells with differing data based on whether or not any one of the cells in each row has a problem/is incomplete.

EXAMPLE:

If I have hundreds of columns that all have different names in column A, and 5 cells in each row have random 1s and 0s, how do I filter out all of the rows that happen to contain 0s in them? Or all 1s? Etc.

Please feel free to ask me to elaborate if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, different names in A, and B to F of each row there are 1s or 0s randomly? And, you want to extract/filter the names with all 0s in B to F or all 1s?

[image]

I expect this is similar to what you said. I hope this is helpful.
1 Line for a copy & paste.

```
=FILTER(A18:F25,B18:B25=0,C18:C25=0,D18:D25=0,E18:E25=0,F18:F25=0)
```

P.S. Oh, The text "A34" in B31 should be "A32".